# No twitter Module error [Mac]

Tags: python, macos, twitter, importerror

I have a python script that follows/unfollows and favorites tweets. I keep getting an error:

```
from twitter import Twitter, OAuth, TwitterHTTPError
ImportError: No module named twitter
```

I put in all the oauth info in my script and i continue to get this error. I think im being blocked from the api. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Have you actually **installed that package?**

Comment: What in that error would lead you to the conclusion that you are being blocked from the API?

Comment: see the pip command, e.g., `pip help`.

Answer (score -1):

First of all: which library do you use? I expect you use tweepy so from a terminal type:

```
pip install Tweepy
```